# Retrieve data from database with ajax load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve data saved to database after users click with load() ajax method

```
<input type="button" class="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart"  value="BUY" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input.add_to_cart').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addprod.php",
            data: $('.prod_form').serialize(),
            success: function(){
                $(".add_cart_msg").delay(250).fadeIn("slow").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                $("#quickcart").load("quickcart.php .quickcart-products");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

After click I want the #quickcart div to be updated and show the new dynamic content. I know thas quickcart.php gets loaded but it doesn't run the sql statement which is correct and without ajax it displays the right content. I;m stuck for hours, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you please add the relevant HTML.

Comment: `load()` expects a URL. not some wonky url/css-selector combo

Comment: You can actually specify elements on the remote page @ValentinRodygin, the syntax is correct. From the docs -  "*The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.*"

Comment: Right, @JayBlanchard. I always forget about this feature.

Comment: @fotant have you watched the request / response in your console? It should reveal any errors.

Comment: @Marc B I also added an absolute url but it didn;t work

Comment: @JayBlanchard the only thing I see in the console is this:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and next to it it shows a jquery file that is totally irrelevant. I know that it loads the page quickcart.php, something else is going on..

Comment: @JayBlanchard now that I removed a line about that jquery that i didn;t need NO ERROS appear..

Answer (score 0):

```
Success:function(data){
//format data.
//$(#elem").empty();
// $("#elem").append(data);
}
```

Your ajax call need to return data. What you're trying to do now is the ajax is calling the php but not getting the data and then awkwardly calling it again to get the data.

Comment: Is your php file returning properly?  Try success:function(data){alert(JSON.stringify(data));}?